# How to enable HTML import in other browsers using polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, html-imports

As title, I used a HTML import link in my site:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://XX.XX.XX.XX/">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
var content = link.import;

// Grab DOM from warning.html's document.
var el = content.querySelector('body');
</script>
```

The variance "link" returns a document in Chrome, but returns null in Safari and other browsers. I know HTML import function is only supported by Chrome so far, so I added the following code before import link to load Polymer's webcomponents.js:

```
<script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

but it still returns null in other browsers, can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `<link>` request is asynchonous.

Catch the *HTMLImportsLoaded* event, to parse the file only when it is loaded by the browser:

```
<script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://XX.XX.XX.XX/XX/warning.html">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener( "HTMLImportsLoaded", function () 
{
    var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
    var content = link.import;

    // Grab DOM from warning.html's document.
    var el = content.querySelector('body');
} )
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. So did it mean it's impossible to enable html import in other browsers?

Comment: To enable HTML Imports Inside , you'll have to include the `webcomponents-lite.js` polyfill, except for Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point, I've already include the webcomponents-lite.js in header, but still not work.

Here are what I've tried:
1) include webcomponents-lite.js before <link> 

2) include webcomponents-lite.js after <link> 

3)include webcomponents-lite.js in "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/XX/warning.html" header tag

but none of them works

Comment: I've updated the `addEventListener` 2nd parameter to make the example cross-browser. Now it should work.